# Confusion on user defined types in f#

Tags: types, f#

For built-in types like int and string, the way to annotate them in a function is like this:

```
let testFunction (x:int) = x * x
```

but for user defined types, the way of using them is different. like the one below:

```
type NewType = NewType of int

let test (NewType a)= a * 2
```

but if i put it in the following way, the intepreter gives me does not match type error (int vs NewType):

```
let test (a:NewType) = a * 2
```

Why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type annotation :

```
let testFunction (x:int) = x * x
```

But in the line :

```
let test (NewType a)= a * 2
```

**this is not a type annotation**. It's called **decomposition** through pattern matching. Pattern matching can be also applied to function parameters like in your example. What it does is unwrapping `int` value contained in your `NewType` and binds it to `a` value. That's why you can do a multiplication because it's done on the `int` value and not on the `NewType`

The last line is also a type annotation :

```
let test (a:NewType) = a * 2
```

It doesn't work because a multiplication is inferred by default to `int` and the annotation indicate that `a` type is of `NewType` and that's why you get this error message. You have to unwrap it like you do `let test (a:NewType) = a * 2`

Comment: oh yeah. Thank you for pointing that out. it made sense when i looked at the signature in the repl. it returned type `NewType = | NewType of int`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing pattern matching with type annotations.  Your second example uses a proper type annotation:

```
let test (a:NewType) = a * 2
```

Unfortunately, this means that you can't access the int parameter to the type constructor without pattern matching to extract it, like this:

```
let test (a:NewType) =
    match a with
    | NewType x -> x * 2
```

The first case that worked for you was not using a type annotation, but was pattern matching as part of the parameter so the value you were trying to access
was already given a name and further pattern matching wasn't needed.  If your type had more than one pattern possible like this,

```
type NewType = NewType of int
             | OtherType of float
```

and you attempted to write the code the first way with a pattern instead of a type annotation, you would see a warning stating that you had an incomplete pattern match:

```
> let testcode (NewType a) = a * 2;;                  

  let testcode (NewType a) = a * 2;;
  --------------^^^^^^^^^

warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, 
the value 'OtherType (_)' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).
```